# Making the ball move with the same speed regardless of resolution (PONG)

Tags: c++, directx, game-physics, pong

I've created a simple Pong game and I move the ball by adding a variable **ballSpeed** to its **position** in my `update` game logic like:

```
void Update()
{
    ballPosition += ballSpeed;
}
```

The problem is that the `ballSpeed` is a `D3DXVECTOR3` with componets: `x = 10; y = 10; z = 0;`

The thing is that when I increase the window's resolution from `640:480` to `1280:1024` the ball is moving slower because it takes more pixels to go.

And my question is: **How can I make the ball move with the same speed regardless of the resolution of the monitor?**

Comment: So you mean "speed" in terms of physical distance? Multiply/divide by the resolution -- isn't this basic maths?

Comment: It doesn't just depend on the resolution of the monitor. It also depends on its size. Consider a 640x480 monitor that is 50 inches vs 10 inches. Unless you are meaning same speed as a % of total monitor size instead of physical speed in the real world.

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can Multiply/Divide by resolution because 640:480 = 4/3 and 1280:1024 = 4/3 so that wont work.

Comment: @Thanatos that's not what he means. He means scale the speed you give by the resolution.

Comment: @Thanatos: I didn't mean divide one part of the resolution by the other part. I mean use it as a _scale factor_. For example, consider **dpi**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the speed by the ratio of the actual resolution to the development resolution. Since the gameplay in Pong is dominated by the horizontal motion, you can use the ratio of the widths:

```
ballSpeed = int(ballSpeed * width / 640.0);
```

You will probably want to do the same to the size of all the screen elements too, such as the ball.

This all assumes that you define "speed" as the time taken to cross the entire screen, not to cover a given number of inches. That calculation would depend on more than just the resolution.

Comment: I end up using this solution modified a little like ballSpeed = ballSpeed * width / 640.0f * height / 480.0f. Thx for the idea:)

Comment: Also, do you need 3 dimensions for the ball?  Reducing to 2 dimensions may speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could introduce a new coordinate system; say from (0,0) to (1,1). Move the ball in this coordinate system, and then map positions in these coordinates to pixels in the screen to draw the ball. You'll want your coordinate system to have the same aspect ratio as the window.

Comment: Yes.  Used a fixed coordinate system for your calculations, then scale it to your resolution for display.

Answer (score 1):

You should first introduce a transform between screen coordinates and logical coordinates, and  update the ball position not by a constant, but take in account the time since the last update, in order to properly simulate the speed.